# Why MFC Ado pplication doesn't work on another computer?

Tags: mfc, ado

I have built an application using VC++ 2015, It is an MFC application I set the project "Cahracter Set= Not set" so I don't need Unicode version.

My application uses ADO to connect to database so

```
try {

    HRESULT hr = m_pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(adoNS::Connection));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(TEXT("CreateInstance succeeded!"));
}
    catch (_com_error& e) {
    MessageBox(e.Description());
}
catch (...) {
    MessageBox(TEXT("OnNewDocument Exception!"));
}
```

So another handling above. When I build the project it runs fine on my computer Windows 7 x64. But If I run the application on another windows 7 I don't get any exception, no CreateInstance succeeded!??

So The problem is with ADO library how can I figure it out please?

After some search I have Copied the folder ADO from the the target machine (another computer running windows 7 x86) to my Computer (with  win7 x64) and VS2015. Now I imported this new ADO library:

```
 #import "C:\Users\User7\Desktop\MyMfcProg\ado\msado15.dll" \
    rename_namespace("adoNS") \
    rename("EOF", "adoEOF")
```

Now if I build it runs fine one both machines! So what is the problem there? Should I link to ADO of each target computer? or the problem just concerns ADO 64 bit and ADO 32 bit?

If so I have an ADO on my win7 x64: 
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado`

I linked to it but the same problem?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: My program is x86 and imported `C:\Program Files (x86)` but it doesn't works on other computer with x86 the application runs but the ADO doesn't even create instance! but bringing a win7 x86 ADO library and importing it on my win7 64 bit it then works fine!!!! I mean it works on any other version of win7 x86 or x64 and even win xp. But what's the matter with  win7 x64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\common files...\ado"?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: But I used in my `stdafx.h`: `#inport C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll"\rename_namespace("adoNS") \
 rename("EOF", "adoEOF")` But it doesn't work on other  x86? I only can copy the ADO folder of win7 x86 to my machine then import this ado so when I build the application it works fine on any other computer?????!!

Comment: I thought you said you have installed 64-bit ADO in `"c:\Program File (x86)\...\ADO"` This would be wrong, and causes problems with any 32-bit programs which will access that file. Avoid installing third party components on common folder. Let the installer figure it out if possible. It should install 32-bit in that location. You could use your own file `"MyMfcProg\ado\msado15.dll"` but there could be an issue with distribution of these components.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I didn't change anything? I have two folders: `C:\Program files\Common files\system\ado` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado`. Could you show me how could i "you have installed 64-bit ADO in "c:\Program File (x86)\...\ADO"? Plaease help.

Comment: Okay I think I got confused about what you are doing. What is the value for `hr` from `CreateInstance`?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I don't know?

Comment: Do mean the program doesn't compile, it doesn't execute `CreateInstance` or you don't know how to print `TRACE("%d\n", hr);` value.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: It compiles fine and builds fine and runs fine on my win 7 x64. but if i run this application on another computer with win7 x86 it runs fine but doesn't't connect to database?!

Comment: Maybe the dll is not registered. I really have no idea. You have to examine the error messages.